# ActionBar Theme not applying

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, themes

I am building an app for a company and I have an activity with a navigation drawer and a framelayout hosting the current fragment (HomeFragment, ProductsFragment...). I have finished all the app logic and it's currently fully operational. I showed the app to the designer and he had the idea of changing the ActionBar color according to the fragment visible at the moment. Well, i saw in a lot of answers even here that i could change via XML > styles > Theme (i tried applying to the application, activity, fragment) like this:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:foreground">#CF0</item>
    <item name="android:background">#CF0</item>
</style>
```

Or i could in runtime force the theme to be changed with:

```
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_blue)));
```

Tried both and well...without any result. The thing is... when i am editing the activity layout I see that the theme is effective and working as i expected, but once i run in my Galaxy S4, it doesnt.

EDIT: Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.main.bohemiadroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.main.bohemiadroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.main.bohemiadroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
        android:name="com.data.bohemiadroid.ApplicationController"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.main.bohemiadroid" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.main.bohemiadroid.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/LoginTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.main.bohemiadroid.AdminActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.main.bohemiadroid.SettingsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.main.bohemiadroid.ImageFullScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Does anyone know what the hell is happening?

Comment: Do you have your Custom Theme defined in styles.xml inside folder values-v14?

Comment: Yes João. I do, i have styles set for values-v14 and values-v11.

Comment: Could you show your Manifest.xml, please?

Comment: If I were you, I would try the runtime approach. Where are you doing it?

Comment: joao2fast4u, just updated my answer with the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 1 day trying to figure out which was the problem. I found a way - I don't know why exactly but the style via XML wasn't working, so I removed the code below from all my themes:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
```

And set it manually, it seems to be working now.